# ReactJS MemoryRouter - Getting current URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**TLDR;**
When using `MemoryRouter`is there any way to get the current URL in App.js? Tried `useLocation()` but it's giving me context errors.

Prior I was using `BrowserRouter` from which I could get `props.location.search` to check for `?resetpassword` (used when called via mail link), but now props holds no data on URL.

I'm switching to MemoryRouter due to getting 404 when reloading page, with no changes to url it now just go to SignIn.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
function App()
{
  return (
    <MemoryRouter >
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={(props) =>
          {
            if (props.location.search.includes('?resetpassword'))
              return <ResetPassword {...props} />
            else
              return <SignIn {...props} />
          }} exact />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact />
          <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword} exact />
          <Route path="/resetpassword" component={ResetPassword} exact />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/app" component={Home} /> 
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm a buffoon. Use `window.location.href` to get full URL path.